# U.S. President has amnesia after terrible war - protected by folks in a small town

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

A short story search. It's been many years since I read this, so apologies if I screw up. (Spoiler alert) The U.S. President is apparently guilty of starting a terrible war, which decimates much of the world. He ends up in a small town, with amnesia, sick and weak, and the folks have figured out who he is. Instead of turning him in for war crimes, they look after him, because of the office he once held, fending off investigators. I am writing a story with a similar theme and want to give credit to my inspiration.

Update: I have searched several databases for clues and used various keyword combos - no luck. Definitely under the categories of speculative fiction, near future, or alternative futures. I would have probably read it in anthology. Had the tone of a classic - Theodore Sturgeon, Poul Anderson, Ray Bradbury - but I am pretty sure not one of those authors - have read them all extensively. Any clues are very welcome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Any idea when it was you read this?  Did you read it in a magazine, an anthology or online?

Comment: Thank you - I believe I read it in an anthology. Would have been before electricity and the Internet. I did not read the sci-fi mags very often.

Comment: Makes me think of "A Clean Escape" by John Kessel, which has a post-nuclear war president with amnesia, but the survivors are _not_ trying to protect him.

Comment: Thank you...this one version is bittersweet, which is why I remember it. The  little indignant speech by one of the town's residents about why they are taking care of him. He is not in good shape, mentally or emotionally. I think it is hinted that he is devastated by what he did, but I might be making that part up.

Comment: I just reviewed the plot of A Clean Escape. Very cool story, but not the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ["Executive Clemency"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53403) by Gardner Dozois and Jack C. Haldeman II, originally published in *Omni*, November 1981, and available in several anthologies. The setup is pretty much as you describe it, with the addition that the United States has collapsed, and the town is effectively independent, though still regarding itself as part of the U.S.

"The U.S. President is apparently guilty of starting a terrible war, which decimates much of the world."

> "Don't you know -- *he caused the War?* ... they made *damn* sure we knew the name of the man who destroyed the world, you can bet on that!

"He ends up in a small town, with amnesia, sick and weak, and the folks have figured out who he is."

> "He came here about twenty years ago, Mr. Brodey. ... The Outriders found him collapsed in a field out by the edge of town. He was nearly dead. ... His memory was almost gone; shock, I guess, and exposure."

"Instead of turning him in for war crimes, they look after him, because of the office he once held"

> "This here is the United States of America, and that poor fool in there --
> why, he's the *President* of the United States of America, even if sometimes he can't cut his meat up proper. ... As long as this town stands, then there's still an America, and that old man will be President as long as there are still *Americans* alive to serve him.

It's a memorable story.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been looking for it for a long time!!